# Why do i have a wrong (sha1) immediate startcom certificate in my chain on azure website?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, sha1, azure-web-app-service, sha256

My immediate certificate on https://paper-shape.com got a weak signature algorithm SHA1: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=paper-shape.com

I followed [theses](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) instructions. I created my pfx file both per OpenSSL and per certificate export wizard.

The CRT and pem (immediate certificate from startcom) seem to be ok, because the following command shows "Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption" on both (CRT and PEM):

> $ openssl x509 -text -in paper-shape.com.crt

Either something went wrong during my pfx creation process or azure website overrules my immediate certificate.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: It looks like it's your certificate provider's cert that's weak, not your cert.

Comment: it's a SHA1 intermediate certificate in chain even though I used a sha256 for my pfx file.

Answer (score 6):

Check your locally-installed certificates (on Windows, 'certmgr.msc'). You may have an old SHA-1-signed copy of the StartCom intermediate certificate which is still valid (say, to 2017) and being used in preference to that provided by the server.

Comment: This is the right answer, main problem is that asking the end user to remove a certificate is kind of hard. The real solution is to configure the intermadiate certificate in your server. See https://sslmate.com/blog/post/chrome_cached_sha1_chains

Comment: I can't check my locally-installed certificates at the azure websites. The problem disappeared by waiting a few days. It was obviously a cache problem...

Answer (score 5):

You can find (and chain) the SHA-256 intermediate certificate for Class-1 in PEM format, here: https://www.startssl.com/certs/class1/sha2/pem/sub.class1.server.sha2.ca.pem

Comment: Hey, i used https://www.startssl.com/certs/class2/sha2/pem/sub.class2.server.sha2.ca.pem, because it's a class2 certificate...

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this same problem, I was about to pull my hair out when the certificate seemed to be right in some browsers and OS and in others it claimed I was using SHA-1 and even https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com was telling me that I had a SHA-2 signed crt.

So! Here is a huge thread in StartCom forum about this issue: https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15929&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

The thing is that the browser is using an Intermediate crt that is SHA-1 signed.

**The solution:** you need to configurate the Intermadiate crt in your server!

You can see more details here:
https://sslmate.com/blog/post/chrome_cached_sha1_chains